# stop word removal code not working, returns same string

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to remove stop words from a string of sentences but my print function returns the exact strings with all the stopwords. Here is the code I am using where `chat_map['Phillips Allen']` is the string of sentences I parsed from a group chat.

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

filtered_sentences_phillip = []
for w in chat_map['Phillip Allen']:
  if w not in stop_words:
    filtered_sentences_phillip.append(w)
print(filtered_sentences_phillip)
```

This code returns this;

```
['Hello?', 'Yeah, how are you?', "Oh, sorry about that. I didn't know.", '(laughter) Oh because of the, the BBA thing?', "you're not going to get paid any bro for this and we'll send you lunch around for the whole desk.", '100 yards...', "hi guys i hope everybody's enjoying there trade this week", 'things seems to be going on well', 'later guys', "don't touch it yet john it's still riding", 'but get ready any moment from now will be closing time', "right now i'm having 64 pips", 'hopping to close higher', 'see you later', 'hi john i hope you closed your gbp/usd long with good pips all green like i did', 'i closed with 76pips', 'whats your position now', "i've taking it short 1.6853", 'just follow and see how it will work out', "so far i'm painting green", 'hi showtime 183', 'join me on skype', 'gbp/usd so far so good john', 'green 45 pips', "i'm still holding john", "but as you said may be it's getting near closing time", 'lets keep an eye out together', 'hi john', "and how's your trading going on", "hi mike and how's trading going on", 'hi steve', 'hi john', "yes i'm trading today john", 'and very busy keeping an eye on it too', "steve how's trading going on", "hard work that's all it takes", "i'd love it if you guys will be my friends on skype", 'i like having fellow traders as friends on skype', 'usd/cad positioned at 1.0939 short', 'eur/chf positioned at 1.2202 long', 'IMO', 'later guys', 'pip watching time', 'hi john', 'been a long time', 'eur/gbp was long', 'but now about to go long any time from now', 'long can still hold on for a while and lets see what the next candle will say at 4h time frame', 'sorry was short and about to go long', 'short can still hold on till the next candle at 4h time frame', 'long position expected', 'eur/gbp going long already', 'how do you see john', 'learn to control your emotions steve this is very important', 'control of emotions is part of success and failure', 'because trading to emotions can lead to and often does lead to wrong decisions', 'making entry and taking exit at the wrong time', 'Hi, John', 'Yes, I remember.', "I'd prefer to keep the actual data", 'Hello mate? You all set?', "Right listen we've had a couple of words with them, you want them lower right?", "Alright okay, alright listen, we've had a couple words with them. You want them lower, right?", 'Glad to hear that you liked it', 'Did you hear last news?', 'Agree. Very promising', 'Happy birthday!']
```

Any idea what's wring please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! While you haven't shown a [mcve] of the contents of `chat_map['Phillip Allen']` it appears you're looking up sentences in a stopwords set. You probably meant to look up individual words in a stopwords set. The entire sentences/phrases aren't going to be in there so they'll all pass the filter.

Answer (score 0):

your source of a problem is that you are not splitting the sentence into words before comparing each word to the list of stop words.
Use `str.split()` function.

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

filtered_sentences_phillip = []
for w in chat_map['Phillip Allen'].split():
  if w not in stop_words:
    filtered_sentences_phillip.append(w)
print(filtered_sentences_phillip)
```

minimalistic reproducible example

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

sentence = 'Yeah, how are you?'
filtered_sentences = []
for word in sentence.split():
  if word not in stop_words:
    filtered_sentences.append(word)
print(filtered_sentences)
```

better formatted reproducible example using python list comprehension

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

sentence = 'Yeah, how are you?'
filtered_sentences = [word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stop_words]
print(filtered_sentences)
```

**output**

```
['Yeah,', 'you?']
```

Note that the output is list of words of processed sentence. If you want to have the sentence as one string use

```py
" ".join(filtered_sentences)
```

**PS:** It's good to do some lemmatization or stemming before removing stop words.